# Recursively merge two arrays, taking alternate elements (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, merge

I really need help with a homework problem. I've been trying to figure this out for days and would really appreciate some assistance! Here's the prompt:

Merge two arrays into one. Write a method named merge which takes 3 interger array
parameters: a, b, and soln. soln is guaranteed to be the size of a.length + b.length. The arrays a and b should be "merged" into one array by alternating elements. Add a 4th parameter, which indicates which element in soln should be updated for a given recursive call of the method.

Examples:

merge({1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, soln, 0) should end with the following values in soln: {1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6}

merge({1,2}, {3,4,5}, soln, 0) should end with the following values in soln: {1,3,2,4,5}

I can get it to work with the arrays are the same length, and even when the arrays differ in length (but only by one element). I can't get the index to line up correctly. I've tried many different variations, but here's what I have so far:

```
public static void merge3(int[] a, int[] b, int[] soln, int index) {
    if (index > soln.length-1) {
        return; //if index reaches end of soln length
    }

        int index2 = (int)(index/2); //allows me to pull alternately from a and b arrays. As index goes up, index2 becomes 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, etc.

        if (b.length >= a.length) {
            if (index%2 == 0) {
                if (index2 > a.length-1) {
                    soln[index] = b[index2];
                    merge3(a, b, soln, index+1);
                } else {
                    soln[index] = a[index2];
                    merge3(a, b, soln, index+1);
                }
            } else {
                soln[index] = b[index2];
                merge3(a, b, soln, index+1);
            }

        } else if (b.length < a.length) {
            if (index%2 == 0) {
                soln[index] = a[index2];
                merge3(a, b, soln, index+1);
            } else {
                if (index2 >= b.length) {
                    soln[index] = a[index2];
                    merge3(a, b, soln, index+1);
                } else {
                    soln[index] = b[index2];
                    merge3(a, b, soln, index+1);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

If array a is {1, 2, 3} and array b is {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, soln becomes {1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 7, 8} instead of what it's supposed to be, which is {1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9}. It's off because when I do index + 1, the recursive call catches on the same value (index2) which was used to alternate between the arrays when there's only one array left. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Are the recursive calls needed?

Comment: Given that this is homework; my advice is to write down the steps you would take if  you had to do this with pen and paper.  These will be the step of your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, we are required to use a recursive call. And I've done that (alternate, then fill in soln with the remaining)--it's just very difficult for me to implement in theory! I've figured out how to merge recursively. But when the lengths of the arrays differ by more than 1, I can't figure out how to draw from the correct index.

Comment: The size of the difference should be immaterial, if its one or 1000 there it shouldn't really matter.  Have you considered that once you hit the first element that is more than the other array has, you just need to copy to from that element to the end of the array?

Comment: Yes, but I can't figure out how to copy the elements from front to end recursively. :( It would be so easy with a for loop! But if I have to call the recursive method again everything gets messed up with my indexes. (Thank you for your help, by the way!)

Comment: its just the same as if it was in a loop really.  In this case ```index``` is outside of the size ```shortArray``` but not ```longArray```, so you just do what you where doing only you no longer take a value from ```shortArray``` and you continue until ```index``` is equal to the size of ```longArray```.  Good luck.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, but it's still not working. Thank you anyway for you assistance! I'll keep trying.

Comment: So it alternates copying from one array, then the other, like @Gavin says, until you run out of one of those arrays.<br>
Let's say you have so many elements in `a` that you'll never run out. When you run out of elements in `b`, what will `index` and `b.length` look like?

Comment: The answer to the question above should look like some pretty basic algebra; no if-statements here. Try drawing a table showing the index you're pulling from, and the value of `index` for each step. You should see a numeric pattern. That's going to be your formula for knowing where to pull from in the larger array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intentionally pedantic approach to thinking through this kind of problem.
Start by determining your state. One way to divide all the possibilities in this problem into distinct states is:

- **exit**, where you will simply return. (always need this for every recursively called method).
- **before array exhaustion**, where you still have at least one array element left in each of the input arrays `a` and `b`.
- **after array exhaustion**, where all of the smaller array's elements have already been added to `soln`
- **array `a` empty** where the first array has no elements. Normally you would handle this outside a recursive call, but we're following rules here...

Each of these states represents a different way that you need to handle your inputs.

The pseudocode for this type of structure would look like:

```
if (test to see if we're in "exit" state) {
    logic handling "exit" state
} else {
    if (test to see if we're in "before array exhaustion" state) {
        logic handling "before array exhaustion" state
    } else {
        if (test to see if we're in "array `a` empty" state ) {
            logic handling "array `a` empty" state
        } else {
            logic handling "after array exhaustion" state

        }

    }
}
recursive call to your method here
```

You already have the `(test to see if we're in "exit" state)` here:

```
if (index > soln.length-1) {
```

and you have the `logic handling "exit" state` here:

```
    return; //if index reaches end of soln length
```

Since this state's logic `return`s, the syntax doesn't require that you put it in an if-else like it is in the pseudocode, but it might be clearer while you're getting a handle on Java syntax if you consistently use the if-else structure throughout.

After that you need your `if (test to see if we're in "before array exhaustion" state)`, conditional, but instead your code assumes you're at `logic handling "before array exhaustion" state` and handles it accordingly. The logic is good, but the state isn't. You'll need to use the template and put that logic in its proper place, but at least you don't have to rewrite it.

Now fill out the rest of the pseudocode template, starting with the tests.

**Tests:**
The `test to see if we're in "array 'a' empty" state` just looks to see if array `a` is empty or not, so it's pretty trivial to write.
The `test to see if we're in "before array exhaustion" state` checks whether we've already copied all of the smaller array's elements into soln yet or not, based on a.length, b.length, and index.

**Array population logic:**
What you've got below your exit case works perfectly for `logic handling "before array exhaustion" state`, so you just need to write:

- `logic handling "array 'a' empty" state` where you already know array `a` is empty.
- `logic handling "after array exhaustion" state`. This is the part where we're all done with the smaller array, and we need to know which element to pull from the larger input array so that we can add it to soln.

So basically follow the template and write the 3 tests (1 already done, one trivial, and one more), and then write the logic for the different states (two already done, one trivial, and one more) and you're there.

You might also consider refactoring your existing code so that there's only one recursive call that happens at the very end. That's called tail recursion, and even with all the optimizations that Java SE 8 has, it's still better this way. It's also a lot cleaner.

Hopefully this is a useful template for thinking through a simple problem.